# pass javascript variable to modal popup form

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, bootstrap-4

On click of `.change_Nodes` class I'm getting value of "id", On confirm box(Yes) I need to pass JavaScript value to modal popup named as `#custom_script_modal`.

```js
$(document).on("click",".Change_Nodes",function(){

  cmd_name = $(this).attr("id");

  if(confirm("Sure to Update \""+cmd_name+"\" Command Executable Nodes?"))
  {
    $('#custom_script_modal').modal('show');
  }
  else
  { return false; }
}
); //update: removed extra curly brace
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="modal fade" id="custom_script_modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h4 class="modal-title text-center" id="custom_script_data_modal">Update Custom Script Executable Nodes</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <form method="POST" id="custom_script_modal">
                    <label class="control-label col-sm-4" for="cmd">List of Nodes</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-8 tab-pan fade in active">
                        <select size="3" name="popup_hostlist[]" id="popup_hostlist" class="dis_tab" multiple>
                            <?php    
                                //-----------Database                                                                           echo "<option value='". $row['NodeName'] . "'>". $row['NodeName'] ."</option>";           
                            ?>
                        </select>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info form-control">Update</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Maybe create a new function which would show the model and also take the argument. Then you can do whatever you like with the argument, inside the function.

Comment: cmd_name = $(this).attr("id"); alert(cmd_name);
function cmd(cmd_name){ alert(cmd_name); } **cmd_name is undefined **

Comment: where is the element with class  `Change_Nodes`  ?

Comment: You're missing a closing bracket at the end of your JavaScript `)`

Comment: `<td><a href="#" title="Add Script Executable Node(s)" class="Change_Nodes" name="Change_Nodes" id="'.$row["Command_Name"].'"><img id="edit" src="images/edit.png" align="EDIT"/></a></td>`  dats the class i'm calling through AJAX @MihaiT

Comment: Nope syntax is correct  but i haven't posted @Matt

Comment: @JhansiPasupuleti OK, I'd update your question so that it works to avoid confusion

Comment: How do you want to use the variable in your modal?

Comment: I want to use that variable in Database select query where clause to fetch records... and iterate through <select> to get <option> values @Tibbelit

Comment: As I understand you, you want to reload (only) the modal (using the value the `id` to get the correct data in the modal) using **ajax**? Is it possible to load the whole modal through ajax in your solution?

Answer (score 0):

As far I understand - you want to change dynamic values for "cmd_name" variable and change it while making any particular selection on the UI and re-use the same modal snippet for those actions.

Set a data attribute on actionable elements for "cmd_name" and access the same variable when prompting the user.

Check out the following JSFiddle and let me know if helps with your case:

```
(https://jsfiddle.net/sunnysharma/xpvt214o/950935/)
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]